# Haskell nested where clauses

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

I am a beginner coder in haskell, while doing an exercise from the first chapter of this amazing book: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/getting-started.html
I came across this issue:

```
-- test comment
main = interact wordCount
 where
     wordCount input = show (ls ++ " " ++ ws ++ " " ++ cs  ++ "\n")
     where
         ls = lines input
         ws = length words input
         cs = length input



wonderbox:ch01 manasapte$ runghc WC < quux.txt
WC.hs:5:9: parse error on input ‘where’
```

Why can I not nest my wheres ?

Comment: Unrelatedly, `interact` is virtually never the right way to do I/O in Haskell.

Comment: @dfeuer: there's nothing wrong with using `interact` for simple “I just want to have that Haskell function in the shell” -kind of programs. Of course `String` is always inefficient, but for many such applications that totally doesn't matter.

Comment: @dfeuer I agree, I am just doing this exercise with the existing boilerplate from the book, I haven't reached the kinda expertise level you have in haskell, but I understand good design and mostly in later stages of the book I'll learn the "right way" thanks for the comment though

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I like when `String` fuses away. @user1639848, I'm no expert; I just know that the old "if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail" applies to Haskell, and some people end up taking `interact` *way* past the point of sanity.

Answer (score 15):

Since your second `where` is attached to the `wordCount` definition, it needs to be indented more than it.  (Although you will still have some other errors afterward.)

Answer (score 11):

Others have already answered. I will just add some more explanation.

Simplifying a bit, the Haskell indentation rule is:

- Some keywords start a block of things (`where`,`let`,`do`,`case ... of`).
- Find the first word after such keywords and note its indentation. Name the column it occurs the pivot column.
- Start a line exactly on the pivot to define a new entry in the block.
- Start a line after the pivot to continue the entry started in the previous lines.
- Start a line before the pivot to end the block.

Hence,

```
where
     wordCount input = show (ls ++ " " ++ ws ++ " " ++ cs  ++ "\n")
     where
         ls = lines input
         ws = length words input
         cs = length input
```

Actually means

```
where {
     wordCount input = show (ls ++ " " ++ ws ++ " " ++ cs  ++ "\n")
     ;
     where {     -- same column, new entry
         ls = lines input
         ;   -- same column, new entry
         ws = length words input
         ;   -- same column, new entry
         cs = length input
         }
     }
```

which treats the second `where` as a separate definition unrelated to `wordCount`. If we indent it more, it will work:

```
where {
     wordCount input = show (ls ++ " " ++ ws ++ " " ++ cs  ++ "\n")
       where {     -- after the pivot, same entry
         ls = lines input
         ;
         ws = length words input
         ;
         cs = length input
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

the indentation was incorrect, here's the working version:

```
-- test comment
import Data.List
main = interact wordCount
    where wordCount input = unlines $ [concat $ intersperse " " (map show [ls, ws, cs])]
            where ls = length $ lines input
                  ws = length $ words input
                  cs = length input
```